# grafana datalink directs to 404 even URL is correct

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I'm using grafana 8.5.0 as part of the prometheus operator project.
Within a panel I set the URL for a  datalink with `/../`  as host to stay with the details dashboard at the same host.
like `/../d/hYipiq0V66/tsn-ncs-540-overview?orgId=1&var-device=${__field.name}`

When I hover over or click the regarding panel the URL is complied correctly like

```
https://myhost:5443/d/hYipiq0V66/tsn-ncs-540-overview?orgId=1&var-device=P5G-SW2-CI
```

but when I click it, I get a [404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJHQC.png)

The URL is correct and when I just click reload the right page opens.
I tested it with Firefox and Chrome, deleted the browser cache, always the same issue.

what's wrong?

I'd expect the right page to open directly w/o that 404 page in between

Comment: Why are you using `/../`? You can simply write `/d/hYipiq0V66/tsn-...` and it will use current host.

Comment: I tried that first, but when I do that it inserts /home/ between the host and the path. I found a similar post where it was proposed to use path tracing /../ to avoid that odd insert.

Comment: This probably means your Grafana configured to use root url `/home`. Check your configuration or env variable `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL`.

Comment: good point.
actually that env var was unset. So, `/home` seems to be a default kind of value for that var.
now I did set it to `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=/` and it works as expected.